# How to track newly created processes in Linux?

Tags: linux, process

I know that with `ps` I can see the list or tree of the current processes running in the system. But what I want to achieve is to "follow" the new processes that are created when using the computer.

As analogy, when you use `tail -f` to follow the new contents appended to a file or to any input, then I want to keep a follow list of the process that are currently being created.

Is this even posible?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

If kprobes are enabled in the kernel you can use `execsnoop` from [perf-tools](https://github.com/brendangregg/perf-tools):

In first terminal:

```sh
% while true; do uptime; sleep 1; done
```

In another terminal:

```sh
% git clone https://github.com/brendangregg/perf-tools.git
% cd perf-tools
% sudo ./execsnoop
Tracing exec()s. Ctrl-C to end.
Instrumenting sys_execve
   PID   PPID ARGS
 83939  83937 cat -v trace_pipe
 83938  83934 gawk -v o=1 -v opt_name=0 -v name= -v opt_duration=0 [...]
 83940  76640 uptime
 83941  76640 sleep 1
 83942  76640 uptime
 83943  76640 sleep 1
 83944  76640 uptime
 83945  76640 sleep 1
^C
Ending tracing...
```

Comment: For new kernel versions (>= 4.17 if I understand correctly) on x84_64, Gregg's perf-tools no longer work - they run but there are no reports at all as it instruments an unused call. According to Gregg's comments elsewhere, the correct solution for kernels >= 4.7, is to use the BPF implementation in the BPF Compiler Collection available here: https://github.com/iovisor/bcc#tools and on Ubuntu and modern linuxes as `bpfcc-tools`.

Comment: This won't include full-paths for executables run with relative paths.

Answer (score 19):

Some examples of [`bpftrace`](https://github.com/iovisor/bpftrace) usage to achieve the goal.

1. The simplest one is tracing all `exec` calls in the system:

   ```
   sudo bpftrace -e 'tracepoint:syscalls:sys_enter_exec*{ printf("pid: %d, comm: %s, args: ", pid, comm); join(args->argv); }'
   ```

   There are at least two tracepoints you need to watch `sys_enter_execve` and `sys_enter_execveat`. In the example I use the `*` symbol to match both syscalls *(this syntax [works since 2019](https://github.com/iovisor/bpftrace/pull/370))*.
2. One may also want to monitor all threads being created in the system as:

   ```
   sudo bpftrace -e 'kprobe:_do_fork{ printf("pid = %d, comm = %s\n", pid, comm); }'
   ```

   No process arguments for you in this case though, nevertheless it may be useful.

To see the list of all available events execute `bpftrace -l`.

Comment: There are two caveats for this solution: first of all, you need kernel headers for bpftrace to work because the ebpf is compiled at runtime. Second of all, the tracepoint and kprobe you mention don't contain full paths for processes run with a relative path.

Answer (score 11):

You can use `forkstat` as stated here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40532202/781153

Install with: `apt-get install forkstat`

And just run: `forkstat`

Answer (score 10):

The easiest way is to enable system call auditing

See the following link for details，

[Does anyone know a simple way to monitor root process spawn | Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/199654/does-anyone-know-a-simple-way-to-monitor-root-process-spawn)

If you're monitoring all processes, just remove the `-F uid=0` part

Logs are written to `/var/log/audit/audit.log`

Comment: None of those 3 links answers my question. The first two are about coding something to resolve this and the last one does not answer neither. What I am asking is about some command and not writing some piece of code

Comment: @PabloMatíasGomez updated

Answer (score 6):

**`CONFIG_PROC_EVENTS=y`**

Sample session:

```
$ su
# ./proc_events.out &
set mcast listen ok
# sleep 2 & sleep 1 &
fork: parent tid=48 pid=48 -> child tid=56 pid=56
fork: parent tid=48 pid=48 -> child tid=57 pid=57
exec: tid=57 pid=57
exec: tid=56 pid=56
exit: tid=57 pid=57 exit_code=0
exit: tid=56 pid=56 exit_code=0
```

`CONFIG_PROC_EVENTS` exposes the events to userland via a [netlink socket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netlink).

proc_events.c

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 700
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <linux/netlink.h>
#include <linux/connector.h>
#include <linux/cn_proc.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

static volatile bool need_exit = false;

static int nl_connect()
{
    int rc;
    int nl_sock;
    struct sockaddr_nl sa_nl;

    nl_sock = socket(PF_NETLINK, SOCK_DGRAM, NETLINK_CONNECTOR);
    if (nl_sock == -1) {
        perror("socket");
        return -1;
    }
    sa_nl.nl_family = AF_NETLINK;
    sa_nl.nl_groups = CN_IDX_PROC;
    sa_nl.nl_pid = getpid();
    rc = bind(nl_sock, (struct sockaddr *)&sa_nl, sizeof(sa_nl));
    if (rc == -1) {
        perror("bind");
        close(nl_sock);
        return -1;
    }
    return nl_sock;
}

static int set_proc_ev_listen(int nl_sock, bool enable)
{
    int rc;
    struct __attribute__ ((aligned(NLMSG_ALIGNTO))) {
        struct nlmsghdr nl_hdr;
        struct __attribute__ ((__packed__)) {
            struct cn_msg cn_msg;
            enum proc_cn_mcast_op cn_mcast;
        };
    } nlcn_msg;

    memset(&nlcn_msg, 0, sizeof(nlcn_msg));
    nlcn_msg.nl_hdr.nlmsg_len = sizeof(nlcn_msg);
    nlcn_msg.nl_hdr.nlmsg_pid = getpid();
    nlcn_msg.nl_hdr.nlmsg_type = NLMSG_DONE;

    nlcn_msg.cn_msg.id.idx = CN_IDX_PROC;
    nlcn_msg.cn_msg.id.val = CN_VAL_PROC;
    nlcn_msg.cn_msg.len = sizeof(enum proc_cn_mcast_op);

    nlcn_msg.cn_mcast = enable ? PROC_CN_MCAST_LISTEN : PROC_CN_MCAST_IGNORE;

    rc = send(nl_sock, &nlcn_msg, sizeof(nlcn_msg), 0);
    if (rc == -1) {
        perror("netlink send");
        return -1;
    }

    return 0;
}

static int handle_proc_ev(int nl_sock)
{
    int rc;
    struct __attribute__ ((aligned(NLMSG_ALIGNTO))) {
        struct nlmsghdr nl_hdr;
        struct __attribute__ ((__packed__)) {
            struct cn_msg cn_msg;
            struct proc_event proc_ev;
        };
    } nlcn_msg;
    while (!need_exit) {
        rc = recv(nl_sock, &nlcn_msg, sizeof(nlcn_msg), 0);
        if (rc == 0) {
            /* shutdown? */
            return 0;
        } else if (rc == -1) {
            if (errno == EINTR) continue;
            perror("netlink recv");
            return -1;
        }
        switch (nlcn_msg.proc_ev.what) {
            case PROC_EVENT_NONE:
                printf("set mcast listen ok\n");
                break;
            case PROC_EVENT_FORK:
                printf("fork: parent tid=%d pid=%d -> child tid=%d pid=%d\n",
                        nlcn_msg.proc_ev.event_data.fork.parent_pid,
                        nlcn_msg.proc_ev.event_data.fork.parent_tgid,
                        nlcn_msg.proc_ev.event_data.fork.child_pid,
                        nlcn_msg.proc_ev.event_data.fork.child_tgid);
                break;
            case PROC_EVENT_EXEC:
                printf("exec: tid=%d pid=%d\n",
                        nlcn_msg.proc_ev.event_data.exec.process_pid,
                        nlcn_msg.proc_ev.event_data.exec.process_tgid);
                break;
            case PROC_EVENT_UID:
                printf("uid change: tid=%d pid=%d from %d to %d\n",
                        nlcn_msg.proc_ev.event_data.id.process_pid,
                        nlcn_msg.proc_ev.event_data.id.process_tgid,
                        nlcn_msg.proc_ev.event_data.id.r.ruid,
                        nlcn_msg.proc_ev.event_data.id.e.euid);
                break;
            case PROC_EVENT_GID:
                printf("gid change: tid=%d pid=%d from %d to %d\n",
                        nlcn_msg.proc_ev.event_data.id.process_pid,
                        nlcn_msg.proc_ev.event_data.id.process_tgid,
                        nlcn_msg.proc_ev.event_data.id.r.rgid,
                        nlcn_msg.proc_ev.event_data.id.e.egid);
                break;
            case PROC_EVENT_EXIT:
                printf("exit: tid=%d pid=%d exit_code=%d\n",
                        nlcn_msg.proc_ev.event_data.exit.process_pid,
                        nlcn_msg.proc_ev.event_data.exit.process_tgid,
                        nlcn_msg.proc_ev.event_data.exit.exit_code);
                break;
            default:
                printf("unhandled proc event\n");
                break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

static void on_sigint(__attribute__ ((unused)) int unused)
{
    need_exit = true;
}

int main()
{
    int nl_sock;
    int rc = EXIT_SUCCESS;

    signal(SIGINT, &on_sigint);
    siginterrupt(SIGINT, true);
    nl_sock = nl_connect();
    if (nl_sock == -1)
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    rc = set_proc_ev_listen(nl_sock, true);
    if (rc == -1) {
        rc = EXIT_FAILURE;
        goto out;
    }
    rc = handle_proc_ev(nl_sock);
    if (rc == -1) {
        rc = EXIT_FAILURE;
        goto out;
    }
    set_proc_ev_listen(nl_sock, false);
out:
    close(nl_sock);
    exit(rc);
}
```

[GitHub upsatream](https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-kernel-module-cheat/blob/e05f447f879a80d9de576c40da7577898e9a6b9e/kernel_module/user/proc_events.c), code adapted from: https://bewareofgeek.livejournal.com/2945.html

I don't think however that you can you get process data such as UID and process arguments because `exec_proc_event` contains so little data: https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v4.16/include/uapi/linux/cn_proc.h#L80 We could try to immediately read it from `/proc`, but there is a risk that the process finished and another one took its PID, so it wouldn't be reliable.

Tested on Ubuntu 17.10, which has `CONFIG_PROC_EVENTS=y` enabled by default.

Comment: Note that for FORK events the parent process isn't necessarily the process that called fork. Rather it is the new process' PPID which can be different.

Answer (score 4):

There are multiple Linux APIs that you can use to do this and multiple usermode tools that use the various APIs. Here are some of the APIs:

- Netlink process connector - this an API to do precisely what you want but there are issues tracking detailed information short-lived processes
- audit API - a kernel API enabled by default on most distributions which can send events to usermode for every syscall (if you go this route you need to track exec-like and fork-like syscalls)
- tracepoints and kprobes - two kernel debugging APIs which can be used to get information on events about process lifecycle
- ebpf based solutions - can be used in conjunction with tracepoints/kprobes to filter the - events in kernel or run various logic
- ptrace based solutions - these include simple ptrace debugging as well as the seccomp API

There are really too many details to properly compare these options in a single StackOverflow answer, but [I've written about this in detail elsewhere.](https://natanyellin.com/posts/tracking-running-processes-on-linux/)

Answer (score 3):

You can apparently *follow* a process using `strace`. If you know the PID of the process then you can do:

```
strace -o strace-<pid>.out -f -p <pid>
```

Notice the `-f` switch. It will help you to follow newly created processes that are descendants of the process whose PID was used in the command, above. For information on strace see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/174942/how-should-strace-be-used) question.

Comment: Apparently you were meaning to attach to the init process, with pid=1, right? Unfortunately it doesn't work, I don't see in the output any creation of new processes, and the number of lines is a few dozens, whilst the current pid for new processes went through a few hundreds.

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR**: use `execnsoop`.

---

- Check that KPROBES are enabled in the Kernel

  ```
  $ zgrep CONFIG_KPROBES= /boot/config-$(uname -r) /proc/config* 2> /dev/null
  /boot/config-4.15.0-64-generic:CONFIG_KPROBES=y
  ```
- Install [BPF Compiler Collection (BCC)](https://github.com/iovisor/bcc)

  - For Debian/Ubuntu the package `linux-headers-*` is also needed:

    ```
    sudo apt-get install bpfcc-tools linux-headers-$(uname -r)
    ```
  - For other distributions see [Installing BCC](https://github.com/iovisor/bcc/blob/master/INSTALL.md)
- Run execsnoop ([examples and options](https://github.com/iovisor/bcc/blob/master/tools/execsnoop_example.txt))

  ```
  root@ubuntu ~ # execsnoop-bpfcc -tx
  TIME(s) PCOMM            PID    PPID   RET ARGS
  5.773   ping             13027  12847    0 /bin/ping hostname
  ```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [SysmonForLinux](https://github.com/Sysinternals/SysmonForLinux) tool which is originally one of the powerful Windows tools released for Linux by the Sysinternals team for collecting most of the system logs including process creation and termination. Its default configuration logs to all process creations.

Comment: Same answer posted on SU: https://superuser.com/a/1691654/399707

Answer (score 1):

you can use https://github.com/radiopushka/pmmanager (Written by me)

and simply run "pmmanager watchdog"

it will list processes that just got launched and ran for longer that 1 second(that being the only downside).
The program should compile and run pretty much anywhere and doesn't need anything. Also it doesn't require kprobes and root.