# Tracing a fork bomb

Tags: linux, fork

I am currently having an issue with a server running CentOS 6. For the past two days around midday we run into what I believe is one of our applications fork bombing the server. We start getting the following error.

```
-bash: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable
-bash: fork: Resource temporarily unavailable
```

I am offsite and unfortunately when the problem is occurring I lose remote access and we have to reboot the box to get it back up. Is there something I can setup ahead of time to log what is forking all these processes? Possibly setup something to log when a process is forked in user space, the parent process and its parent pid. Something to help me debug this from the system level. I searched U&L and Google with plenty of examples of how to cause a fork bomb but nothing on how to trace it or find the source.

Comment: See: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/260162/how-to-track-newly-created-processes