# How to get this list? Don't miss any [PID] (running & ended)

Tags: boot, process, command, ps

How to get this list (table)?
From turn on the computer until now.
**Don't miss any [PID] (still running [PID], already ended [PID]).**

List field: **PPID, PID, Threads, USER, Start-time, Change-time, End-time, full-Command**

Among:

- [Start-time]: Start time of the process
- [Change-time]: Process change time. When [PPID] or [full-command] changes
- [End-time]: The end time of the process.

Comment: To get previous process information you will need to be running something to capture this information. Traditionally this is part of the `sa` (system accounting). However this will not tell you about the currently running processes. Why do you want this information? We might be able to suggest an alternative approach.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/260162/how-to-track-newly-created-processes-in-linux

Comment: What's **Threads**? If it's the number of threads, note that the number of threads of a process goes up and down during the lifetime of a process. euid, ruid can also change.

Comment: What's the OS(es)? Note that computers can run more than one OS after they've been *turned on*. Presumably you want the list of processes handled by *this kernel* or maybe at least since `init` was started if you don't care about the processes started in an init ramdisk for instance.

Comment: What's **full command**? Is it contents of strings passed in the `argv[]` parameter to `execve()` system calls made by the process?

Comment: The OS is Linux OS. I use Arch Linux now.@StéphaneChazelas   
The "full-command" is the "command" in `ps -ef`.    

I tried this, but it couldn't catch everything. Some processes ended in less than 1 second.   
`watch -n 1 'ps -auxf >> ps-auxf1.txt'`

Comment: I tried acct, which is a bit close if the following problems are solved. @icarus 
[link](https://www.gnu.org/software/acct/)  
1. 'lastcomm' output short command (no options), the maximum length is only 15. Since there are no options, you don't know what it does exactly.  
2. 'lastcomm --pid': can output (pid, ppid). But not all, using pid sorting, you will find that many pids are missing. Some processes are not recorded.  
3. Required filtering options (per boot to the next boot).

Comment: If export to a file, and then do the analysis. Their problems are:  
4. Import excel sheet. There will be problems with the text to columns because the width is inconsistent, so you cannot use fixed-width the text to columns.  
 (The length of 'pid, ppid' is inconsistent, resulting in a change in the column width)  
> Suggest: If fix the 'pid, ppid' width and write to the configuration file, the default is 6 digits, which is not enough to modify the configuration, there is no problem.

Comment: 5. Use 'awk' spaces to separate columns, The number of columns is inconsistent, such as:  
'command' column: some will have blanks, some with spaces in the middle (dconf worker). So there may be 0 columns, 1 column, 2 columns.  
> Suggest: If not limit the length of 'command' and move this column to the last column, there is no problem.  

'flags' column: some will have blanks, some with spaces in the middle. So there may be 0 columns, 1 column, 2 columns.  
> Suggest: If the blank part of the output uses a (-), like this : (S   X) > (S---X) there is no problem.

Answer (score 1):

You're better off using something like auditd which will hook into each system call. The problem with using ps or in-fact anything that uses the proc filesystem is stuff can get missed, especially if that stuff (or it's user) actually wants to be missed and effectively invisible.

The proc filesystem is a point in time view of the processes. In fact, its a few points in time as processes with larger PIDs are scanned slightly later than ones with smaller PIDs.